# preg_match to only allow 10 digits an no special characters or spaces

Tags: regex

I have the following function: `preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/'` to only allow 10 digits.  How ever if i enter 041 123456 it accepts it.  how do i prevent spaces?  I want the user to enter the phone number as 041123456 only.  no spaces or special characters must be allowed.

the code i am using is

```
If( ($fax_1_length != 0) | preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/', $fax_1) ){
    $fax_1_lenght_valid = true;
    $fax_1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['fax_1']));   
    }
    else
    {
            $mistakes[] = 'ERROR - Your 1st Fax Number should only contain numbers or is empty.';
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Problem is this line:

```
if( ($fax_1_length != 0) | preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/', $fax_1) )
```

`|` is used for bitwise ORing.

You should be using `&&` instead of `|`

```
if( ($fax_1_length > 0) && preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/', $fax_1) )
```

Which will execute if block when length > 0 && phone number contains 10 digits only.